# Suppose $f \in L^p[0,1]$ for what values of $\lambda$ , $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \int^{\epsilon}_{0} f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f \in L^p[0,1]$ , $0 \leq p \leq \infty$ , for what values of $\lambda$ $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \int^{\epsilon}_{0} f = 0 \ \ (*)$$

This is a problem in Roydens's book, **My attempt** :

let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ then the limit would look like $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1/n}_0 n^{\lambda}f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_0 n^{\lambda}f \chi_{[0,1/n]} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1}_0 f . g_n$$ Where $g_n = n^{\lambda} \chi_{[0,1/n]} $ . I want to use Holder's inequality, but before that I have to use a convergence theorem to pass the limit inside the integral sign. $\{g_n\}$ is not bounded (BCT can't be used), not monotone (MCT can't be used), not dominated by an integrable function (DCT can't be used) ... Any Hints/Ideas are appreciated :)

**THE CORRECT APPROACH** added later

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int^1_0 f \frac{\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \leq  ||f||_p  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} ||\frac{\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}}{\epsilon^{\lambda}}||_q$$
We want $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} ||\frac{\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}}{\epsilon^{\lambda}}||_q$ to be zero i.e. $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} ||\frac{\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}}{\epsilon^{\lambda}}||_q = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left[ \int^1_0 \left( \frac{\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \right)^q \right ]^{1/q}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \epsilon^{1/q} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon^{\frac{1}{q} - \lambda}$$
If $\frac{1}{q} - \lambda > 0 $ we'll find the values of $\lambda$ for which (*) holds. i.e. $$\lambda < 1- \frac{1}{p} \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$$

Comment: You have shown the statement is true for $\lambda < 1 - 1/p$, but not the converse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to apply Holder's inequality to $\int^\epsilon_0 f dx = \int^1_0 f\cdot1_{[0,\epsilon]} dx$ and then study the possible limits.

Comment: thanks ! I'll update the full answer

Answer (score 0):

The condition holds for all $\lambda<0$ (provided that $p\geq1$).

By Hölder's inequality, for $p>1$,
\begin{align}
\varepsilon^{-\lambda}\int^\varepsilon_0f\leq \|f\|_p\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{q}-\lambda}
\end{align}
where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. Thus,the desired property holds at least for all $\lambda<\frac1q$.